# Java: How do I call the array from different class, and I do I modify them?

Tags: java, arrays, function, class, instance

I'm a beginner in Java programming, and I'm trying to make a 2 player board game that the players move around the board according to the result of dice (1~6).

The blank arrays are used to show the players' location.
`blank[i][0]` is the first player's location on the board, `blank[i][1]` shows the second player's.

I created the array in the `class Blank{}` and want to use this in functions of the `class Player{}`. This is the code for `class Blank{}` and a part of the code for `class Player{}`

```
class Blank {
    
    Blank() {
        String[][] blank = new String[12][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <2; j++)
                blank[i][j] = " ";  }
    }
}
```

```
class Player {
    
    int player1, player2;
    
    Blank blank = new Blank();
    
    Player() {
        player1 = 1;
        player2 = 2;}
    
    void readyPlayers() {
        blank[0][0] = player1;
        blank[0][1] = player2;}

    int getPlayer1() {
        int i = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (blank[i][0] == "1")
                break;}
        return i;}

   void setPlayer1(int p1Loc) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            blank[i][0] = " ";
        blank[p1Loc][0] = player1;}

   void movePlayer1(int dice1) {
        int p1Loc = getPlayer1();
        for(int i = 0; i < dice1; i++) {
            p1Loc += 1;
            if (p1Loc == 10)
                p1Loc = 0;}
        
        setPlayer1(p1Loc);}
```

I thought the functions in `class Player{}` would work because of the line `Blank blank = new Blank()`, but there is this array in every `blank[][]` array.

error: `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Blank`

Comment: Variable `blank` is not an array-type, hence the compiler-error. The code is in a state where I cannot recommend any fix (I am not even able to fully deduce what the program is supposed to do). I recommend reading a tutorial on Java and OOP, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Comment: "I changed my code according to the advice you gave me. " Don't do that, this a Q/A site not a forum, by change your question you make the other answers obsolete and nonsensical

Comment: Didn't know this..my bad

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very good description. You should fix it. I'll still try to help.
If you are trying to record their position on the board, just use one array arr[2] or two different variables. Also I don't think you need to use a String array. In getPlayer1, you don't need to put break. return automatically breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you create a local variable into the Blank constructor, but when you get out from there blank variable will no longer be availabe.

Secondly, into the functions, you try to write an int into a String, but you do in the wrong way. Read here [Convert int to String](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-int-to-string) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The `Blank blank = new Blank();` is a class instantiation and cannot be used as you stated which is `blank[0][0] = player1;`. The variable `blank` can only be used to call methods rrom your class `Blank` e.g lets say your `Blank` class has a method `exampleMethod()`

```
public class Blank {

    Blank() {
        String[][] blank = new String[12][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <2; j++)
                blank[i][j] = " ";  }
    }

    public void exampleMethod(){
        //write your code here
    }
}
```

This is how you would call it from a method in your `Player` Class

```
public class Player {
    int player1, player2;

    Blank blank = new Blank();

    Player() {
        player1 = 1;
        player2 = 2;}

    void readyPlayers() {
        blank[0][0] = player1; //instead of these
        blank[0][1] = player2; ////instead of these

        blank.exampleMethod(); // This is how to use the instantiated blank class. 
    }
}
```

So I would advice you refactor your code.

Comment: I changed my code a bit. Do you think this would work?

Comment: @ICIS Don't do that because you my the questions obsolete